# Persistant TCP Connection To Speed Up Remote File Fetching

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that uses file_get_contents to fetch a file on a remote server on every page load.  Is it possible to make a persistent connection between the two servers to speed up the time it takes to fetch this file?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Even if you open a connection to the remote server PHP would have to close it at the end of the script. A PHP script should just run as long as it needs time to do all task to present the user a site.

Comment: If you're trying to get content of same file, have tried caching?

Comment: The file changes on each load

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP process is likely ending each request, so you will have to handle this outside of the main PHP process.

I would recommend setting up Nginx as a proxy, and pointing your PHP script at Nginx.  You can then configure Nginx to use HTTP/1.1 keep-alive, which will keep a persistent connection open if requests are coming through regularly.